# Exporting multiple variables in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, environment-variables

I am having trouble exporting multiple env variables in a for loop of a bash script.

The full script looks something like:

```
IFS_old="$IFS"
IFS=';'
test_data="secret1='data1';secret2='data2';secret3='data3'"
for secret in $test_data
do
    eval "export $secret"
done
IFS="$IFS_old"
```

So the input string consists of variables and their values separated by a semicolon.
I loop through it and want to export each of them; however, the variables that get exported have "null" values.

I also tried composing a full command string in a separate variable, and executing it both via         `bash -c "$command"` and `eval "$command"` statements, but it didn't work.

Can you please help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: How do you know the variables are not exported? When I add `export | grep secret` to the script I see all of them.

Comment: Your approach would break if one of the `data` parts contained a semicolon, and of course there is a danger of code injection; so unless you build up the `test_data` by yourself and know exactly what's in, it's really risky to use `eval`. Perhaps it makes sense to redesign the data structures. Where do the variable-value associations actually come from? Why do you have to put them into such a nasty string?

Comment: BTW, if you add a `printenv` at the end of the string, you should see all the exported variables. If you would use **exactly** that program you posted, your variables `secret1` and so on should be listed.

Comment: @user1934428 , thanks for the info.
I completely control the data that is getting exported as env variables;
But I totally agree with you, it would be easy to inject code if given access to the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine. The variables exported are local and only available until the end of your script. When the script closes they are no longer available in the shell. This is normal.
if you write `bash` on the last line of your script it will open a new terminal with the exported variables available.